# What is the best way to show an encrypted database value in a view?

Tags: security, encryption, view, asp.net-core-2.0

I am encrypting 2 properties on a model when they are saved to the database with the Data Protection APIs in ASP.NET Core.

I'm currently decrypting it before showing it in the view but this can't be the right way to handle a scenario like this?

```
   //GET: admin/editBankaccount
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditBankAccount(string id)
    {
        var bankAccount = await _context.GetBankAccountAsync(id);

        //decrypt bankaccount no. and reg.

        var bankNo = _protector.Unprotect(bankAccount.AccountNo);
        var regNo = _protector.Unprotect(bankAccount.AccountReg);    
        bankAccount.AccountNo = bankNo;
        bankAccount.AccountReg = regNo;

        return View(bankAccount);
    }
```

There must be a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What about this needs to be simpler?  How would you like it to work?

Comment: It just seems very clumsy? I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle encrypting/decrypting model properties in the database